# Uploadify in MVC3 does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, uploadify

Can't get this to do anything. When I click 'Upload File' absolutely nothing happens as well as I don't see any of the flash rendered to the screen. I believe this is somehow related to the jquery, but I am not sure. PLEASE HELP! If someone can mail me a simple VS2010 solution with uploadify working to infinitimods at gmail.com that actually works I'd appreciate even more! Thanks a bunch!

```
My Layout file:

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
        <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" media="screen" href="/Scripts/uploadify/uploadify.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/uploadify/swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/uploadify/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/uploadify/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        @RenderBody()
    </body>
    </html>



My index file:

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

    <h2>Index</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {        
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $("#file_upload").uploadify({
                    'uploader': '~/Scripts/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
                    'cancelImg': '~/Scripts/uploadify/images/cancel.png',
                    'buttonText': 'Upload foto',
                    'script': '/Home/UploadFiles',
                    'folder': '/Content/upload',
                    'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
                    'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png; *.txt;',
                    'scriptData': { 'thisGuid': $("input#Id").val() },
                    'multi': false,
                    'auto': true,
                    'onError': function (event, queueID, fileObj, errorObj) {
                        alert("Error!!! Type: [" + errorObj.type + "] Info [" + errorObj.info + "]");
                    }              
                });

                $("#btnSave").button().click(function (event) {
                    $('#file_upload').uploadifyUpload();
                });


            }); 

        </script>

        <input id="file_upload" type="file" />

        <input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Upload file" />

        <input id="Id" name="Id" type="hidden" value="5168e-yada-yada" />
    }

My controller:

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Index");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileData"></param>
    /// <param name="form"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpPost]
    public string UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase fileData, FormCollection form)
    {
        return "ok";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Uploadify requires jQuery. This means that you need to include the jQuery script **before** the uploadify script. If you had looked in your javascript debugging console you would have seen this error.

So, the layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/uploadify/uploadify.css")" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/uploadify/swfobject.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/uploadify/jquery-1.4.2.min.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/uploadify/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.4.min.js")"></script>
</head>

<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

The controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase fileData, string thisGuid)
    {
        if (fileData != null && fileData.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var appData = Server.MapPath("~/app_data");
            var file = Path.Combine(appData, Path.GetFileName(fileData.FileName));
            fileData.SaveAs(file);
        }
        return Json(new { status = true });
    }
}
```

and the view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#file_upload').uploadify({
            'uploader': '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/uploadify/uploadify.swf")',
            'cancelImg': '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/uploadify/images/cancel.png")',
            'buttonText': 'Select photo',
            'script': $('form').attr('action'),
            'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
            'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png; *.txt;',
            'multi': false,
            'auto': false,
            'onError': function (event, queueID, fileObj, errorObj) {
                alert("Error!!! Type: [" + errorObj.type + "] Info [" + errorObj.info + "]");
            }
        });

        $('form').submit(function () {
            $('#file_upload').uploadifySettings('scriptData', { thisGuid: $('#id').val() });
            $('#file_upload').uploadifyUpload();
            return false;
        });
    }); 
</script>


<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{        
    <input id="id" name="id" type="hidden" value="5168e-yada-yada" />
    <input id="file_upload" type="file" name="fileData" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload file" />
}
```

And if you want to kick the uploading process when the user selects a photo you could get rid of the form and the submit button and set the `auto` property to `true`:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#file_upload').uploadify({
            'uploader': '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/uploadify/uploadify.swf")',
            'cancelImg': '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/uploadify/images/cancel.png")',
            'buttonText': 'Select photo',
            'script': $('form').attr('action'),
            'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
            'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png; *.txt;',
            'multi': false,
            'auto': true,
            'scriptData': { thisGuid: $('#id').val() },
            'onError': function (event, queueID, fileObj, errorObj) {
                alert("Error!!! Type: [" + errorObj.type + "] Info [" + errorObj.info + "]");
            }
        });
    }); 
</script>


<h2>Index</h2>

<input id="id" name="id" type="hidden" value="5168e-yada-yada" />
<input id="file_upload" type="file" name="fileData" />
```

Also don't forget to checkout the [uploadify documentation](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/) to better understand what the different options are used for and also you can see some examples.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work around a bug with asp.net and flash.

This article helped me once: [Working around flash cookie bug](http://geekswithblogs.net/apopovsky/archive/2009/05/06/working-around-flash-cookie-bug-in-asp.net-mvc.aspx)

Maybe this is a better solution: [jquery file upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)