# string parameter null in controller action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I'm trying to upload a file with ASP.NET MVC Partial view.

```
**Partial view:**

@using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Item", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id="frmUp" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
}
```

**Main Form:**

```
<div id="uploadDiv" class="divSettings" align="left">        
    @Html.Partial("FileUpload")
</div>
```

In my main form i have the below code.

```
$("#frmUp").submit(function () {
    var serviceURL = '/Item/FileUpload/';
    var id = $("#selID").val();
    alert(id);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: serviceURL,
        data: { id: id },
        dataType: "json",
        success: successFunc,
        error: errorFunc
    });

    function successFunc(data, status) {        
    }

    function errorFunc() {
    }
});
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file, string id, FormCollection formCollection)
{
    //here id parameter is null and i get the file parameter values
    return PartialView();
}
```

In my controller id parameter is always null. whats the issue with the above code?

Comment: You can not post file with ajax. You should use an ajax file upload plugin...

Comment: For example: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal it's just a hidden field with a static value. i didn't post the code for that

Comment: Have you define selID inside the same form?

Comment: @Amit: It doesn't have to be, the code will find it anywhere in the page.

Comment: Where is Jquery code. If it is out side then It will not work. Define selID inside the form and then it will come in action

Comment: @Guffa : Amit made a very good point. When I submit the form and control goes to `Post Action Method` and Hidden field is outside the Form, you cannot except to retrieve the Hidden Field value in `Post Action Method` Model parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approach - 1**

**[Ajax FileUpload](https://github.com/jfeldstein/jQuery.AjaxFileUpload.js)** plugin uploads the file somehwere, and passes the
response to a callback, nothing else.

- It does not depend on specific HTML, just give it a `<input type="file">`
- It does not require your server to respond in any particular way
- It does not matter how many files you use, or where they are on the page

-- Use as little as --

```
$('#one-specific-file').ajaxfileupload({
  'action': '/upload.php'
});
```

-- or as much as --

```
$('input[type="file"]').ajaxfileupload({
    'action': '/upload.php',
    'params': {
    'extra': 'info'
    },
    'onComplete': function(response) {
    console.log('custom handler for file:');
    alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    },
    'onStart': function() {
    if(weWantedTo) return false; // cancels upload
    },
    'onCancel': function() {
    console.log('no file selected');
    }
});
```

**Approach -2**

```
@model FileUpload
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("YourActionMethod", "ControllerName", new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST"
    }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "frmUp" }))
{
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="FileInfo" value="File to Upload" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourActionMethod(UploadFileModel fileModel)
{
    return View();
}

public class UploadFileModel
{
    public HttpPostedFileBase FileInfo { get; set; }
}
```

If you pay attention to the above code, I am using `Ajax.BeginForm`. Besides this, I will recommend to use View-Models to pass data back to you `Action Method` instead of FormCollection.

[image]

### **Why View Models and not FormCollection?**

I have four issues.

*Issue - 1*

In case `FormCollection` is being used...It will be mandatory to Type Cast the `Primitive` Type Values un-necessarily because while getting the entry of specific Index of the `System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection`, value being returned is of type String. This situation will not come in case of Strongly Typed `View-Models`.

*Issue - 2*

When you submit the form and goes to `Post` Action Method, and View-Model as Parameter exists in the `Action` method, you have the provision to send back the Posted Values to you View. Otherwise, write the code again to send back via `TempData/ViewData/ViewBag`

*Issue - 3*

While Preparing Unit Test cases, again you will face the same issue mentioned in **Issue-1**. It's very big problem, when code is written in following manner. As Request is not available in the *Unit Test cases*.

```
public ActionResult MyActionResult()
{
    String value = Request.Form["Key"];
    return View();
}
```

*Issue - 4*

We have `Data Annotations` that can be implemented in `View Model` or `Custom Validations`.

**[image]**

### **Approach - 3**

**[Uploadify - Please check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10118445/2015869)**

**Note** - In order to retrieve the Posted valued in `Post Action Method` the controls, it
is must to keep the controls inside the form tag. Likewise, your `Hidden Fields` should also be inside the Form tag in order to get it's value in the `Post` Action Method

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stopped the normal action of the form, so you will both be posting it as usual, and sending an AJAX request.

It's the regular posting of the form that gives you the `null` value for `id`, as the form doesn't have any field with that name.

Use the `preventDefault` method at the start of the function to stop the form from being posted:

```
$("#frmUp").submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  ...
```

This will make the AJAX request reach the server instead of the regular posting of the form, however the `file` parameter will always be null as you can't post a file using AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve AJAX-like file posting you have to use 3rd party AJAX plugins, Flash uploader or anything else what have access to file system under a web browser.

However, if you don't want to mix technologies you can always use hidden iframe approach. In fact, I've been using this approach in a project I've been recently working in and it worked pretty fine!

Below are some helpful resources:
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/ajax-style-file-uploading-using-hidden-iframe/
[Jquery File Upload Hidden IFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369726/jquery-file-upload-hidden-iframe)